# ‘obj_type’ was not declared in this scope, note: suggested alternative: enum Value_type

Tags: c++, enums, scope, json-spirit

I'm using JSON Spirit to parse and generate json.

I cannot use `using namespace json_spirit` because another library uses conflicting names.

I'm trying to detect the type [as specified here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented#val) of a read message with

```
if(message.type() == obj_type)
```

but the compiler reports

```
error: ‘obj_type’ was not declared in this scope
       if(stamper_message.type() == obj_type){
                                    ^
note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/local/include/json_spirit.h:13:0:
/usr/local/include/json_spirit_value.h:32:22: note:   ‘obj_type’
     enum Value_type{ obj_type, array_type, str_type, bool_type, int_type, real_type, null_type };
```

I have also added this line

```
using json_spirit::Value_type;
```

and this line

```
typedef json_spirit::Value_type Value_type;
```

but it doesn't help.

I apologize for such a simple question, but I cannot find a solution, so how can this `enum` be imported for use in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [a very old Q&A](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/538941-how-get-enum-different-namespace):

```
using json_spirit::Value_type;
Value_type obj_type = Value_type::obj_type;
```

I will delete if someone posts something better or a way to declare all enum members in one line.

Comment: It's not working in my code. can you help me please?