# How to access enum present as a template class member in another namespace?

Tags: c++, enums

I'm working on c++, following is my template class:

```
namespace My{    
template<class config>
class BasicValue
{
public:
    enum Type
    {
        NULL_TYPE = 0,
        OBJECT_TYPE,
        ARRAY_TYPE,
        STRING_TYPE,
        BOOL_TYPE,
        INT_TYPE,
        REAL_TYPE,
    }; // Type
};// BasicValue

}// My
```

Now, Im accessing this "Type" enum from another .cpp file. Im getting following compilation error for all enum types:

```
error: ‘STRING_TYPE’ was not declared in this scope
```

How I can use this enum outside the "My" namespace?

Following is the code usage, Im using the enum value in switch case:

```
void printValue(const Value& val, int space)
{    
    int sp = space;
    switch(val.type())
    {
        case STRING_TYPE:
            break;
        case BOOL_TYPE:
            break;
        case INT_TYPE:
            break;
        case REAL_TYPE:
            break;
        default:
            exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code that tries to access `STRING_TYPE`. Provide this in a small example that can compile.

Comment: 3 things wrong: having the `enum` as a class member does not reflect its use; having the values named in all uppercase is suitable for Java or Python but very counter-productive for C++; and the code is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @All please check, I have pasted code

Comment: There is nothing in the `enum` that is specific to the template parameter. You can put it in `My` namespace.

Comment: @RSahu yes you are rite, but its not my code its a standard library code (json-spirit) that I'm using. :)

Comment: I already answered this. What is the mystery?

Comment: Still trying to figure this out?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992445/obj-type-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-note-suggested-alternative-enum-val/21992862#comment38486656_21992862

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
My::BasicValue<int>::Type t;           // get an instance of the type
....
t = My::BasicValue<int>::STRING_TYPE;  // get a value
```

but this assumes you fix all the syntax errors in the code, as [in this example](http://ideone.com/pcGXXZ)..